# Equivalent of Coq's `Eval` for Agda

Tags: agda, agda-mode

Coq has an `Eval` command that you can use to have the type-checker evaluate an expression and print it to the console. Is there an equivalent to this in Agda? In particular, I'd like to avoid actually compiling and executing the program. I just want to introspect a value to make sure my code is working (and help me understand it better) before I go to the effort of writing proofs.

It's fine if the solution involves agda-mode (as compared to Coq, where it's part of the language).

Comment: Have you read through the supported functionalities in agda-mode yet? It's right there. Do a quick in-page search (Ctrl-F in browser) if you need to. And by the way we have a [site for proof assistants](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution: <kbd>Ctrl-C Ctrl-N</kbd> in agda-mode allows inputting an expression and then prints the evaluated result.